# Unable to resume activity after picking image from camera

Tags: java, android, camera, photo

Here is methods for open camera. I dont know the specyfic starting of this error, sometimes i got this error and sometimes didnt. I dont know why my stupid teammate use the spaghetti code for getting the image from camera, but i need resolve it.

So why i think about add other resultCode for handle something wrong
What are u guys think?

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO) {
                Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(photoAbsolutePath);
                onPhotoResult(imageUri);
            } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_OPEN_GALLERY) {
                Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                onPhotoResult(imageUri);
            }
        }
    }
protected void onPhotoResult(Uri uriPath) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Tools.loadBitmapFromGallery(uriPath, getActivity());
    if (bitmap != null) {
        float angle = Tools.getRotation(uriPath, getActivity());
        if (angle != 0f) {
            bitmap = Tools.rotate(bitmap, angle);
        }

        RequestUploadPhotos requestUploadPhotos = new RequestUploadPhotos();
        byte[] photo = new Tools().getImageData(bitmap);

        try {
            File tempFile = File.createTempFile("temp", ".jpg");
            if (tempFile != null) {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
                fos.write(photo);
                fos.close();
                requestUploadPhotos.photoFilesList.add(tempFile);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (requestUploadPhotos.photoFilesList != null) {
            UploadPhoto uploadPhoto = new UploadPhoto();
            uploadPhoto.execute(requestUploadPhotos)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(response -> {
                        if (response.getSuccess()) {
                            List<ImageUrl> addedPhotos = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.newGalleryPhotos.size(); i++) {
                                addedPhotos.add(new ImageUrl(
                                        response.newGalleryPhotos.get(i).getImageId(),
                                        response.newGalleryPhotos.get(i).getImageUrl()));
                            }
                            myGalleryAdapter.addPhotosToGallery(addedPhotos);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), response.getActionRes(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }, throwable -> throwable.printStackTrace(), () -> {
                    });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error forming request", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}


java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {.NewMainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65536, result=-1, data=null} to activity {NewMainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3176)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3207)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:168)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1378)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5665)
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:689)
                                                        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65536, result=-1, data=null} to activity .NewMainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3778)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3163)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3207) 
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544) 
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:168) 
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1378) 
                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150) 
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5665) 
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799) 
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:689) 
                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
                                                           at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:477)
                                                           at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:467)
                                                           at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:439)
                                                           at co.spontime.ui.fragments.UserProfileFragment.onActivityResult(UserProfileFragment.java:307)
```

Edited:

```
@RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
private void dispatchTakePicture() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
            Log.i("DispatchTakePicture", "file created:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "Error, while creating a directory \n" +
                    ex.toString());
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            try {
                photoAbsolutePath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(),
                        "co.spontime.fileprovider", photoFile);
                getContext().grantUriPermission("com.android.camera", photoUri,
                        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                //you must setup this
                takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                Log.e("TakePhoto", "Failed providing Uri from FileProvider");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your UserProfileFragment.java:307 line? and where do u get `photoAbsolutePath`?

Comment: Edited with method photoabsolutePath

Comment: are you testing the android build on samsung ?

Comment: Only in LG and Huawei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes beacuse inside onActivityResult method your using
  Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(photoAbsolutePath); where photoAbsolutePath may be null.

you should get uri from data intent.Apart from it you should use same request code whatever you have taken at the time of startActivityForResult.

Comment: Edited with String photoabsolutePath

Comment: Inside onActivityResult instead of photoabsolutePath ,get uri from intent like this Uri imageUri = data.getData();

Comment: So i should change String to uri?

Comment: Replace this line  Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(photoAbsolutePath); with Uri imageUri = data.getData(); only then try

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.net.Uri android.content.Intent.getData()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

This is my javaCode that I use to save picture on Android 8 and Android 10 , respectively Android Oreo and Android Q:

//altura = Height;
//largura = Width();

```
        if (requestCode == CAMERA && data == null) {//Android 10 (Android Q > API 23)
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            //     Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(image_uri, proj, null, null, null);
            Cursor cursor = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getContentResolver().query(image_uri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String caminho = cursor.getString(column_index);//diretorio
            cursor.close();

            try {

                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), image_uri);

                int altura = bitmap.getHeight();//altura;
                int largura = bitmap.getWidth();//largura

                if (largura > 450) {

                    if (altura > largura) {//retrato

                        bitmap = getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 450, 600);
                        saveImage(bitmap);
                    }

                    if (largura > altura) {//paisagem

                        bitmap = getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 600, 450);
                        saveImage(bitmap);
                    }

                    if (largura == altura) {//quadrado

                        bitmap = getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 450, 450);
                        saveImage(bitmap);
                    }

                    apagaFotoOriginal(caminho);

                }

                salvarBD();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Falhou!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            atualizarLista();
        }
```

Before I use this linecode to get the imageUri from the cursor that i have requiseted on Camera Intent:

> //     Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(image_uri, proj, null, null, null);

And after I choose for this:

> //     Cursor cursor = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getContentResolver().query(image_uri, proj, null, null, null);

CameraIntent:
private void abrirCamera() {
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
image_uri = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

```
    //Camera intent
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image_uri);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA);
}
```

This worked with me, can you try..